# CodeIgniter always shows 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using [codeigniter-3](/questions/tagged/codeigniter-3) and I have set its default controller in `routes.php` as

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

I have set the `Virtual Host` for this project and my `.htaccess` looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^[A-Za-z0-9_/\-\.]*$ - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My config.php is like

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

It is working fine if the default controller is set to `welcome`

Comment: check your controller file name is `home.php` and controller class is `Home`.I am sure you copied the file and forgot to change the class name.

Comment: Should it be checked for colon too in rewite rule of allowed characters?

Comment: Have you made sure all the controllers are capitalized like Welcome.php

Comment: Yes they all are capitalized

Answer (score 0):

If your folder tree is something like this : `htdocs/codeigniter/`

Then use the following codes in .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And check your `controller` class name and file name if same.